# How to find reason for crash from production stack trace

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an Xamarin Android app in production. In google play console I can see many instances of the same crash, however I am not able to reproduce it locally. Stack trace is quite generic:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
... 1 more
Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at MyApp.Activities.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x001a4>
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0005b>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.2b42a88f-c445-435d-aa7c-f905596cf5db (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>

at md5317d85657469e27a0cec50bfaa82e3ea.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
at md5317d85657469e27a0cec50bfaa82e3ea.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
... 4 more
```

So I can see the crash is in `OnCreate` of my `MainActivity`. But where?

Is is possible that the crash is in some method called from OnCreate and stack trace is not accurate? Because my OnCreate pretty much just call other method, very few lines of code in the method itself:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

#if DEBUG_FRAGMENTS
    FragmentManager.EnableDebugLogging(true);
#endif

    var userSettingsManager = new UserSettingsManager(this);
    Window.SetFlags(userSettingsManager.FullScreen ? WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen : 0, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainLayout);

    if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 17 && Window.DecorView != null)
    {
        Window.DecorView.LayoutDirection = Utils.LocalizationHelper.IsLanguageRTL(userSettingsManager.Language) ? Android.Views.LayoutDirection.Rtl : Android.Views.LayoutDirection.Ltr;
    }

    if (this.ActionBar != null)
    {
        this.ActionBar.Hide();
    }

    InitializeSomething(userSettingsManager);

    InitializeSomethingElse();

    InitializeStuff();
}
```

What is the number at the end of this line

```
at MyApp.Activities.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x001a4>
```

Can it somehow help me find the exact line of the null reference? In common .NET errors there are IL offsets, but this doesnt seem like one.

Comment: Getting same stacktrace from Samsung Galaxy Tab at API 22, when application is in background for some time and is then shown again. We have code in place that intercepts this very behavior, but crash happens somewhere before MainActivity.OnCreate - my first line there is log output, and I don't see it. Logs show the application is correctly SaveInstance-d and killed before, but something is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Might help to get a free account at Crashlytics and integrate that into your code.

Should help get reports on live production crashes.

See https://try.crashlytics.com/ for more info.

[UPDATE] Please ignore this. Crashlytics is not supported by Xamarin (As of this writing). Will leave post here though in case it helps someone coming across article but are developing natively

Comment: Does it support xamarin? I cant find any informaiton

Comment: Yep, my apologies, only realized now that Xamarin is not supported by Crashlytics